# How to create such form for android tablet screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi i want to create form for tablet screen i tried to create view using custom background but it seems looks not nice well.So is any option to design a screen [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wpFz.gif)

I tried to achieve the list table by using listview.i got horziontally line using divider height but i didn't able to get vertical line.Please anyone help me to design the screen like this..Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use TableLayout a great example is here => http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/

Comment: @SelimYILDIZ but datas in that table is a dynamic one.

Comment: You can add row and column with programatically. @New bee